# Disable attribute for HTML input based on a bool parameter from Controller - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to make an input visible based on a bool variable?

`<input type="button" value="Smth" onclick="...">`

I am trying to find an HTML helper for this purpose, however no luck so far.

Comment: visible by css or in code? in code you can use Razor @if(true) { <input......> } or css <input style="visible: @visible" ...>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve your required result to set your `input` field as disabled by using the `ternary conditional` operator:

```
<input type="button" value="Smth" onclick="..." @(myBoolCondition == "true" ? "disabled='disabled'" : "") >
```

Where `myBoolCondition` is your variable holding the result of your condition.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
@if ( your bool condition)
{
<input type="button"   value="Smth" onclick="..."> //visible
}
else
{
<input type="button" class="d-none" value="Smth" onclick="..."> //none-visible
 
//or

<input type="button" hidden value="Smth" onclick="...">
}
```